# Run a complex series of commands in the same Docker container

Tags: lxc, docker

I'm trying to automate the following loop with Docker: spawn a container, do some work inside of it (*more than one single command*), get some data out of the container.

Something along the lines of:

```
for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    spawn a container
    wget revision-i
    do something with it and store results in results.txt
```

According to the documentation I should go with:

```
for ( ... )
    docker run <image> <long; list; of; instructions; separated; by; semicolon>
```

Unfortunately, this approach is not attractive nor maintanable as the list of instructions grows in complexity.

Wrapping the instructions in a script as in `docker run <image> /bin/bash script.sh` doesn't work either since I want to spawn a **new** container for every iteration of the loop.

To sum up:

1. Is there any sensible way to run a complex series of
   commands as described above inside the same container?
2. Once some data are saved inside a container in, say, /home/results.txt,
   and the container returns, how do I get results.txt? The only way I
   can think of is to commit the container and tar the file out of the
   new image. Is there a more efficient way to do it?

Bonus: should I use vanilla LXC instead? I don't have any experience with it though so I'm not sure.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually came up with a solution that works for me and greatly improved my Docker experience.

**Long story short**: I used a combination of [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.6/tutorial.html) and a container running sshd.

**Details:**

The idea is to spawn container(s) with sshd running using Fabric's *local*, and run commands on the containers using Fabric's *run*.

To give a (Python) example, you might have a *Container* class with:

1) a method to *locally* spawn a new container with sshd up and running, e.g.

```
local('docker run -d -p 22 your/image /usr/sbin/sshd -D')
```

2) set the env parameters needed by Fabric to connect to the running container - check [Fabric's tutorial](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.6/tutorial.html) for more on this

3) write your methods to run everything you want *in the container* exploiting Fabric's run, e.g.

```
run('uname -on')
```

Oh, and if you like Ruby better you can achieve the same using [Capistrano](http://www.capistranorb.com/).

Thanks to @qkrijger (+1'd) for putting me on the right track :)

Answer (score 1):

On question 2.

I don't know if this is the best way, but you could install SSH on you image and use that. For more information on this, you can check out [this page](http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/examples/running_ssh_service/) from the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You post 2 questions in one. Maybe you should put 2. in a different post. I will consider 1. here.

It is unclear to me whether you want to spawn a new container for every iteration (as you say first) or if you want to "*run a complex series of commands as described above inside the same container?*" as you say later.

If you want to spawn multiple containers I would expect you to have a script on your machine handling that.
If you need to pass an argument to your container (like `i`): there is being work done on passing arguments currently. See https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/pull/1015 (and https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/pull/1015/files for documentation change which is not online yet).